# R: ties.method = random : How to always obtain the same randomization when ranking with ties.method = random

Tags: r

I am working with R and I am sharing my r project with some colleagues. At one point in my code, I use a ranking and I use this code...

```
Data2 <- Data1 %>% 
    group_by(Target) %>% 
    mutate(myRank = rank(desc(nTimes), ties.method = "random")) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

The problem that we have is that every time we run the code the randomization changes and we need to randomize the ties just one time and then use the same document in order to reach the same results.

There's is a way to always get the same randomization when using ties.method?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe try `set.seed(12345)`?

Comment: Probably `set.seed(11)` previous to your `Data2 <- ...`-code helps to make results reproducible. See `?set.seed()`for help.